# Intersection Of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_n$ vector spaces above $\mathbb{C}$
>
> Prove: $V=\cap_{k=1}^{n}V_k$ is a vector space

Now the qeustion that rises is:

a. What is the relation between the $V_i$'s, can we assume that all are a subspace of a bigger dimension $U$ vector space? else we can have that $\emptyset=\cap_{k=1}^{n}V_k$?

b. Do we need to prove that $V$ is a vector space or can we assume that it is a subspace of the sum of the $V_i$'s using $dim(U+V)=dim(U)+dim(V)-dim(U\cap V)$

Comment: No, it only make sense if all of them are subspaces of some bigger space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is badly phrased. Intersecting unrelated vector spaces makes no sense; they need to all be subspaces of one vector space. More precisely, for the intersection to make sense they all need to be *subsets* of a containing set, but if that is the case while their vector space structures are unrelated, there is nothing one can say about the intersection (and indeed it could be empty).

However, if indeed they are all subspaces of one vector space$~V$ (which means their vector space structures are all derived from that of$~V$), then indeed the intersection is also a subspace of$~V$. To prove it just check the three conditions for a subspace: containing the zero vector (in particular the intersection will not be empty), and being closed under addition and arbitrary scalar multiplication. This holds for the intersection because it holds for all the subspaces being intersected. Dimension plays no role in this.

Comment: That is what I thought, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HINT

you have to check the three properties for a linear subspace:

1. $0 \in W$
2. $w_1 \in W, w_2 \in W \implies w_1+w_2 \in W$
3. $w_1 \in W, c \in \mathbb{K} \implies cw_1\in W$

Think also at some special and simple example for $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$.